# What's new in WPF 3D in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, wpf, 3d

Did anyone find something? Even a little thing? Does anyone know if anything has been quietly announced in the blogosphere or anywhere else?

Comment: This is more of a discussion than a question.

Comment: No, it is a valid question. There are many 'what's new in ...' questions on SO. I don't get the downvotes here.

Comment: I too would think that question like this belong here. Would anyone explain what wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2):

Please see this discussion

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a5c4a77c-6d38-41e6-a90f-f1a32fe43de2